openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") is not working in Jupyter
I am using a Mac.
I am programming in Python using a Jupyter notebook (version 4.0.15) loaded from Anaconda Navigator 2.6.2.
I want to load my OpenAI key from the environment.
This is my code:
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
print(os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"))

The above code returns "None"
In terminal it says .zsh, not Bash at the top of the terminal window. (I think I had a message saying zsh was better than bash which was maybe deprecated, so I ran some code to change it to zsh.)
I believe I have correctly got my openai key into the Terminal environment because when I type:
echo $OPENAI_API_KEY, it correctly returns my openai api key starting with "sk-"....
I have no problem making everything work if I hard-code the API key into my program.  I have restarted my Mac many times, but no luck.
I have looked at many of the answers here, but I still can't get this working. I couldn't find an answer relative to my specific setup. I just want my API code to be passed to the program from the environment.

Doesn't seem to be any point to run openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") if
print(os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")) returns None. 'OPENAI_API_KEY' is a Operating System environment setting like JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk.... Have you set it for the environment you are running your code in?

moken:  You ask the question "Have you set it for the environment".  As written in the question:  When I type echo $OPENAI_API_KEY inn the terminal, it returns my OpenAi API key.    If I have misunderstood your question please explain more.

All I am saying is if print(os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")) returns None then there is no point to read that environment variable. It does not exist in the environment you are running your Python script irrespective of what echo $OPENAI_API_KEY does at the command line.

Moken:  I think what you are saying is that python runs in an environment which is not the same as the environmemnt i am running in my terminal program.  So to get this working I guess I have to either change the environment of my terminal, or change the environment that my Jupyter notebook is using.  I spent some time here looking for questions like "What is an environment?" or "How do I change the environment?", but I get a bunch of related questions and answers, which don't directly answer those questions.   It looks like I am the only person here who asked this.  I'll keep searching.
